# Euclidean Geometry (Potential Menelaus Theorem)

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have a strong suspicion that this problem applies Menelaus's theorem, but I can't see it. I also tried algebraic manipulation (such as trying to re-write BD/DC in terms of AB or CP), but to no avail. I'd appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\frac{BD}{DC} \frac{CE}{EA} = -1$ then $\frac{AF}{FB}=1$ where $F$ is a point on the line through $AB$ as in Menelaus' theorem. Then it follows that $AF = FB$. Therefore $F$ has to lie halfway inbetween $A$ and $B$. This means the triangle is flat.

Comment: I agree with what you've said, but how does that help to establish a relationship between CP and AB?

Comment: And I'm not too sure what you mean by a "flat" triangle...

Comment: @FrenchToastCrunch All points of the triangle lie on the same line

Comment: Btw. you can also use Ceva's theorem to get the same result

Comment: Hmm, why do you assume that if AF=FB that the triangle is flat? I understood everything else.

Comment: try drawing the triangle